# PHP - Proper JSON format not being returned?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using the below code to return JSON data to my mobile application (I'm posting data to the Stripe server to create a customer and return a key to my iOS application). That said, when I post to this endpoint, the customer and key are created in the Stripe backend (awesome), but the following error comes back to my app - is my PHP formatted incorrectly? I'm under the impression that my code should be returning JSON... but my error is telling me it's not.

**Error message:**

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016
> "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(

));
    
     $key = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(
      ["customer" => $customer->id],
      ["stripe_version" => $_POST['api_version']]
    );

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode($key));
    
    
}
```

**JSON response when navigating to PHP file in browser:**

```
{"id":"ephkey_000","object":"ephemeral_key","associated_objects":[{"id":"cus_iD","type":"customer"}],"created":1601166469,"expires":1601170069,"livemode":false,"secret":"ek_test_key_here"}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `exit(...)` with `echo json_encode($key); exit;`?

Comment: When you run the PHP in the browser, does it echo correct JSON data?

Comment: @kmoser Same error occurs :/

Comment: @SaachiTech No, but that's only because the code is missing variables that POST to it via my application (these variables obviously arent populated when I just navigate to the url via my browser).

Comment: @Brittany You can fake it by writing `$_POST = ['api_version' => 'whatever' ];` just to see what JSON the script outputs. I'm guessing something else in the script is throwing an error, causing PHP to output a `Content-Type: text/html` header.

Comment: @kmoser When I navigate to the link (after taking your advice and populating those variables), it spits out what appears to me to be perfect JSON, ha ha. See it posted in my question :)

Comment: Ahh I fixed it @kmoser. Just realized mbstring wasn't installed on my server's version of PHP. Only discovered that by populating those variables manually though as you suggested, as it then caused my code to spit out an error on the browser :) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Brittany Cool! I've taken the liberty of writing my comment as an answer. If it helped you, please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as "accepted".

Comment: @kmoser Done :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test your script in the browser by adding `$_POST = ['api_version' => 'whatever' ];` just to see what JSON the script outputs. I'm guessing something else in the script is throwing an error, causing PHP to output a `Content-Type: text/html` header.